# Predicate throws Exception in Cocoa ObjC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a array of dictionary. I'm trying something like

```
ANY student.project_code BEGINSWITH[cd] "N8"
```

The error thrown is

**Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = `<null>` rhs = N8)**

The issue is some of the students doesn't have a project code. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Can you modify your data model to store empty strings instead of nil for students that don't have a project code? This would fix the problem as everything would be a string.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite actually the data is returned from server. Hence that can't be done. And here json is directly converted to dictionary using an universal class.

Comment: Since you're not actually using a database of any kind, you could use a block predicate instead — the performance won't be any slower, and you'll get the full power of real code.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite any link to guide me to block predicate

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a block predicate instead:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:BOOL ^(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [((NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject)["@project_code"] hasPrefix:@"N8"];
}];
```

Block predicates are similar to normal predicates, except instead of evaluating a predicate string against each object, it simply calls a custom block that you provide, passing it the object being tested currently, and you return `YES` if the object matches your rules, and `NO` otherwise. This gives you far more flexibility, as you can run any code in your block, and aren't restricted to SQL-style conditions.

The above code creates a predicate for filtering an array of dictionaries, each having a `project_code` key (if the key doesn't exist the method will return nil, so the check will be false, which is exactly what you want anyway).